# How make all strings in list one length?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of names and I need to format it to make all strings same length (add spaces where it needs). Im using java 8 and already got the largest string of list, and I have no idea how to compare other strings to that largest and add spaces where it has to.
My code:

```
List<String> names = formatNames(abbreviations);
    String max = Collections.max(names, Comparator.comparing(String::length));

private String adjustableString(String format, int number) {
    return IntStream.range(0, number).mapToObj(i -> format).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: You should be more specific about the intended result. Do you want to change the list or print the formatted strings or do something else?

Comment: It is possible to display Strings with the same maximum length without changing the String values in the List.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the max length of the strings and then align them using `String.format`:

```java
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("a", "bbb", "12345");
int maxLen = names.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max().getAsInt();

names.stream()
     .map(s -> String.format("%-"+ maxLen+"s", s)) // use "%-5s" to add spaces to the left, "%5s" - to the right
     .forEach(f -> System.out.printf("[%s]%n", f));
```

Output:

```
[a    ]
[bbb  ]
[12345]
```

---

**Update**
Of course, a case of empty list could be handle using `orElse(0)`, but there is another opportunity to chain calculation of optional max length with replacement of values inside the array using `List::replaceAll` similar to [fps' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64560194/13279831):

```java
static List<String> padAllToMaxLength(List<String> list) {
    list.stream()
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .max()
        .ifPresent(max -> doPad(max, list));
    return list;
}

private static void doPad(int spaceCount, List<String> list) {
    System.out.println("doPad: " + spaceCount + ", " + list);
    if (spaceCount > 0) {
        Map<Integer, String> spaces = new HashMap<>();
        list.replaceAll(s -> s.length() == spaceCount ? s
                : s + spaces.computeIfAbsent(spaceCount - s.length(), (x) -> " ".repeat(x)));
        System.out.println("space cache: " + spaces);
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing to pad");
    }
}
```

Test

```java
String br = "\n====";
System.out.println("empty list: " + padAllToMaxLength(Collections.emptyList()) + br);
System.out.println("empty values: " + padAllToMaxLength(Arrays.asList("", "", "")) + br);
System.out.println("values: " + padAllToMaxLength(Arrays.asList("", "1", "22", "333", "44", "5", "", "777")) + br);
```

Output

```
empty list: []
====
doPad: 0, [, , ]
nothing to pad
empty values: [, , ]
====
doPad: 3, [, 1, 22, 333, 44, 5, , 777]
space cache: {1= , 2=  , 3=   }
values: [   , 1  , 22 , 333, 44 , 5  ,    , 777]
====
```

Comment: Fails with exception if the list is empty.

Comment: @Andreas, updated for the edge case using `Optional::ifPresent` + `List::replaceAll` + `String.replace`

Comment: Why not just replace `getAsInt()` with `orElse(0)`? If the list is empty, the `map()` lambda expression won't execute, so the value is unused, and hence doesn't matter.

Comment: if the list is empty, max() is empty and `ifPresent` will take care of it as well.

Comment: Given the amount of unnecessarily repeated work for every element, it’s just consistent to max it out by replacing the simple `"%-"+ maxLen+"s"` with the long winded `"'%-Xs'".replace("X", Integer.toString(max))`…

Comment: @Holger, you're right, it should have been moved to a separate method

Comment: I don’t think that maintaining a cache for space `String` instances string will pay off. The complexity of a `HashMap` will rather disturb the JVM’s optimizer. Just use `String spaces = " ".repeat(spaceCount); list.replaceAll(s -> s + spaces.substring(s.length()));` You could eliminate the temporary substring using `list.replaceAll(s -> new StringBuilder(spaceCount).append(s) .append(spaces, s.length(), spaceCount).toString())`, but it’s not clear how it compare to the former when using  to JDK 9+ string concatenation plus JVM optimizer.

Comment: The most extreme version would be `char[] buffer = new char[spaceCount]; list.replaceAll(s -> { s.getChars(0, s.length(), buffer, 0); Arrays.fill(buffer, s.length(), buffer.length, ' '); return new String(buffer); });` which does not bear any temporary object on the application’s side, but, as said, it’s not clear whether this is really necessary in an optimizing environment. I’d first try how `String spaces = " ".repeat(spaceCount); list.replaceAll(s -> s + spaces.substring(s.length()));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format()` with a format string of `"%-99s"`, where `99` is the max string length:

```java
int maxLen = names.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);
String format = "%-" + maxLen + "s";
names = names.stream()
             .map(s -> String.format(format, s))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The terminal operation should of course be what you need, whether building a new list (like shown here), printing them, concatenating them, ...

Comment: In case of `maxLen == 0` - either for empty list, or if list contains only empty Strings -- there's no need to build `format` String and run the stream :)

Comment: Adding to what Alex said above, one can use `.max().ifPresent(i -> ...)` but on one condition: "effectively final". So in this case, names can be mutated directly from inside the lambda body. Beware: Don't use parallel if you are not sure what it can do.

Comment: @AlexRudenko and in case of `maxLen == 1`, it is more efficient to use `.map(s -> s.isEmpty()? " ": s)`. There are lots of possibilities to improve the performance, as `String.format` is one of the worst operations, performance-wise. However, it’s simple and works and more is not necessary, giving how little information we have about the OP’s actual requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers show how to create a new list with the strings formatted. Here's a way to format the strings of the list, in-place:

```
names.replaceAll(s -> String.format("%-" + max.length() + "s", s));
```

This assumes that `max` is the string of the list with max length. It uses [`List.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-), which accepts a unary operator to transform all the elements of the list.

Answer (score -1):

You can format a string and add spaces where it's needed with `String.format`:

```
String.format("%1$"+length+ "s", string);
```

Just pass the max length and all your strings to the above method.

Comment: That will add spaces *before* the string, not after.

Comment: @Andreas, you're right. The question does not specify where spaces should go. It's likely that the spaces are needed on the right, but it depends on the type of data contained in the strings.